# Error when querying Salesforce REST API - order object with full query, but works fine with limited results and querying just one field

Tags: rest-api, query, sobject, order

I'm encountering an issue when performing a REST API query for order object on Salesforce, specifically when using a full query that includes multiple fields. However, the query works perfectly fine when I limit the results or query just a single field. Here are the details:

REST API Query:

```bash
https://myorg.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v54.0/query?q=SELECT+LastModifiedDate%2CSBQQ__Quote__c%2COpportunityId%2CStatus%2CQuoteId%2CAccountId%2CFsys_AccountName__c%2CIsDeleted%2CId+FROM+Order+WHERE+SystemModstamp+%3E%3D+2023-06-28T01%3A11%3A01Z+and+SystemModstamp+%3C%3D+2023-06-29T01%3A11%3A01Z
```

Error message:

```json
[
  {
    "message": "Unable to complete the creation of the query cursor at this time, please retry your query later.",
    "errorCode": "FUNCTIONALITY_TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE"
  }
]
```

I've noticed that when I have just 1 field in the query or add a limit to the results, the query works without any issues. However, when I include all the desired fields, the error message mentioned above is returned. This issue arises only for the orders object, and works fine for all other objects.

I have considered possible factors like API limits, system load, or query complexity, but I'm not entirely sure what might be causing this specific issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem when querying Salesforce via the REST API for order object? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the community Athithya, This looks like an intermittent issue. check this here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1887 . You mentioned it worked  when LIMIT is added. Did it run with all the fields with LIMIT?

Comment: This likely a bug - open a support case.

Comment: `SBQQ__Quote__c%2COpportunityId` - this doesn't look like a valid relationship name; you also need [queryAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_queryall.htm) to access deleted records

Comment: @Prabhan Thanks for the welcome. Yes it did run will all the fields in limit. Weirdly enough when I removed the limit, it throws the error I mentioned.

Comment: @identigral I also feel it's most likely a bug.